# Newark Airport transfer - Luggage collection and drop off

Tags: luggage, layovers, ewr

I am traveling from Europe to Las Vegas.  Newark is my transfer city and I need to get from Terminal B to C.

My questions is - when I collect my baggage on Terminal B, do I have to recheck it in Terminal B or take it to Terminal C and there drop it off?

Comment: What airline is your connecting flight from EWR to LAS?

Comment: @NateEldredge There's only one domestic airline that flies from terminal C - United (well, plus their United Express carriers, but that doesn't change anything)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Are you traveling on a single reservation, or did you purchase your EUR-EWR and EWR-LAS tickets separately?

Comment: @choster Doesn't fundamentally change the answer as there are transfer (check-in) desks at the re-check area. (yes, it's one extra step, but the process is largely the same regardless)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this exact connection yesterday, so...

Once you clear immigration/customs in terminal B you will immediately come to the baggage re-check area.  Presuming that your bags are already tagged all the way to LAS then you will simply need to drop them at the re-check area.  If your bags are not already tagged then there are counters available where they will be able to check you in for your next flight and tag your bags.

Once you've dropped your bags, the preferred route is to then to head to the (free) AirTrain which will take you to Terminal C where you can pass through security and go to your gate.  It is also possible to clear security in terminal B and then catch the air-side bus to terminal C but this will most likely be slower and more complex to work out the route.

Comment: Thought I'd mention that as far as the last suggestion goes -- re-clear security in B and take airside bus -- I'm not sure you can actually even do that, according to [this page](https://www.newarkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights) on the Newark Airport website: "In addition, United operates a **one-way** shuttle bus connecting Terminal A to Terminal B (Gates B60 to B68) and Terminal C to Terminal B (Gates B60 to B68) between the hours of 1:00 pm and 11:00 pm (i.e., **customers in Terminal B cannot use the shuttle bus to go to Terminals A and C**)." [emphasis mine]